# validating a cell in a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in a Windows Form, it has 2 columns, the last column is going to contain the name of a packet, the point is that this name never has to be duplicated.

I tried with this code using CellValidating event

```
        string value = Convert.ToString(dgvTiendas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
        int cellIndex = e.RowIndex;

    if(cellIndex == 1)
    {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dgvTiendas.Rows)
            {
                if (cellIndex == rw.Index)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    string valorRow = Convert.ToString(rw.Cells["ContenedorCodigoBarras"].Value);
                    if (value == valorRow)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The container is already used");
                        dgvTiendas.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Contenedor ya utilizado";
                        e.Cancel = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Cancel = false;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

When i run the application and i write a container's name, it is validated but it seems that validate the current cell because the "Error text" appears on the RowHeader.

Please help i have some weeks with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are having this problem because you are setting the error text of the row with this code.

```
dgvTiendas.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Contenedor ya utilizado";
```

You need to set error text of the cell

```
dgvTiendas[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "an error occured";
```